# Move Yii2 existing messages from php array to po gettext file

Tags: yii2, gettext, message

We have existing translation files in Yii2 in php array format and would like to transform them into `po/gettext` format.

There is a php2po tool, and you can run

`php2po -P messages/en pot/`

But i'm looking for a better solution for elements like numeral translations. Like:

```
return [   
'{n,plural,=1{file} other{files}}'=>'{n,plural,=1{arxiuvo} other{archivos}}',
]
```